# Return the MIN and MAX date based on selected date/week

Tags: excel

I want to return the MIN and MAX date based on selected Date on my Excel.

Example: Today is 3/15/2023, I want to create a formula that would return a value MIN Date: 3/13/2023 and MAX Date: 3/17/2023

[image]

Comment: Do you mean to return the Monday/Friday date based on the selected date?

Comment: yes exactly, sorry i didnt include that explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The excellent answer from @Kairu could be simplified slightly to reduce the number of function calls, since we know Friday will always be Monday + 4:

```
Monday(B2): =B1-WEEKDAY(B1,3)
Friday(B3): =B2 + 4
```

Comment: This is what I did yesterday, I forgot to respond here, but yeah this works perfectly! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming your selected dates will always fall on a weekday

Monday: `=B1-WEEKDAY(B1,3)`

Friday: `=B1+5-WEEKDAY(B1,2)`

Comment: Thank you for this! This is the first step, followed by the answer below then it's all perfect!